# Second Clause in a Matrix Clause?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, infinitive-clauses

I thought to read on matrix clauses. In

> 25) [Bill wants [Susan to leave]].

I think in text this seemed like a matrix clause. Matrix clauses get called that in that they contain two clauses? I may not get where these clauses get placed. I think a clause requests a verb and arguments. I may get *Bill wants Susan to leave*, one clause, *Bill* (subject[?], *wants* (transitive[?] verb[?]), Susan (object[?]), *to leave*, (I may not get). I may not get where a second clause seems here?

Comment: Matrix clause = main clause = independent clause, and embedded clause = subordinate clause = dependent clause.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *Susan to leave* is a **subordinate clause**, which functions as **one** single element within the main clause:

> - Bill (subject)
> - wants (predicate/verb)
> - Susan to leave (object)

However, subclauses can normally be broken down on their own level as well, though this is not very straightforward here because we're dealing with a **non-finite subclause**. You could say that *Susan* is the subject while *to leave* is the predicate.

You could try to convert the non-finite subclause to a finite one, but that does not really work in this case. You would be left with a rather unnatural sentence:

> Bill wants *that Susan leaves*.

However, now it is more clear that *Susan* is indeed the subject and *leaves* the verb. And still the whole subclause *that Susan leaves* functions, as a whole, as a direct object in the main clause.

Comment: Non-finite subclauses seem interesting. I may read on that. I may get *Susan* like a subject, I may not get *to leave*. I guess I thought a subordinate clause contains a subordinate conjunction or maybe relative pronoun. I guess I may mostly not get *Susan to leave* if it seems like maybe a dependent clause. I may not get what dependent clause. Maybe it seems like a noun clause, maybe? And I guess I thought predicates place information maybe on a verb, if *to leave* seems a predicate, I may not get that. I may not get what maybe verb it places information upon.